# Using RMAIL to send an e-mail

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, sendmail

I'm struggling to find documentation that gives a clear example of how to enter a message in the rmail application.

I need to specify who the email is from, the subject of the email, and then follow that with some content. It's for a small school assignment where we are relaying "status updates" from imaginary machines on an imaginary factory floor.

This is the closest I've found, but it is not very clear: http://www.s-gms.ms.edus.si/cgi-bin/man-cgi?rmail+1

Can anyone give me an example of how I would send a message that looked like this? (obviously not including the comments...)

> /* header stuff */
>
> From: something@something.com
>
> Subject: Status update for machine 5
>
> /* message content */
>
> Machine ID: 7
>
> Status Reported: Machine going offline (status 6)
>
> Status effective: 2012-06-02 12:30:23

I am opening rmail via software controlled pipe in my application without problems, I'm just not sure how to format the data I am feeding to it since I can't find any examples online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably interested in using /usr/bin/mail on most modern Unixes, not rmail.

You should read the man page, but generally, it would be sufficient to use the "-s" flag to set the subject of the mail, and input the content of the message on stdin. There is no need to set the From: line, as the system will do that for you (and in the general case, the system will not let you specify arbitrary from addresses to prevent forgeries.)

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot for the reply, unfortunately it's a school project and it's specified that I used rmail, and also specified that I set the from address to a specific sender. I'm currently using sendmail which works fine, and the content is like so:

From: someemail
Subject: somesubject

random content

...It intelligently parses out the "from" and "subject" and puts them in the right places in the email. I just need to figure out what I have to provide as input to rmail to get the same results.

Comment: No modern system will, in the general case, let you set the "From" address to something arbitrary. In any case, "rmail" became obsolete with the end of UUCP, which has been dead for well over a decade, you should probably ask the instructor if using /usr/bin/mail is okay (and I bet they'll say yes).

Comment: @Perry: I've been using rmail from emacs (`M-x rmail`) for some weeks now and haven't had any problems. Is there a situation where rmail will fail to do its job that I am unaware of? Also, if rmail is obsolete, is there another emacs module that you would recommend? Keep it up.

Comment: rmail in emacs has nothing to do with the (long obsolete) shell command of that same name. If you are looking to read email in emacs, there are a large number of options (of which rmail is certainly a possibility.)